# jwplayer.resize() not working as expected

Tags: jwplayer

On this page http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1413089-javascript-api-reference it says resize() can take percentage number as parameter but when I try

```
jwplayer().resize(50%,50%)
```

There is a syntax error saying `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,`

Moreover, when try to run the following code in console, it simply print the funciont body instead of execute it

```
var s = 500;
jwplayer().resize(s,888);
```

However, if I include it in the js files, it can be executed without problem. So how do I make resize take percentages and why it won't execute in console(which make it hard to test and debug)?

Comment: It'll print the function body if the fn you executed returns itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
jwplayer().resize('50%','50%');
```